# How to intercept packets from RTP-stream on loopback and access the data through C++-code?

Tags: network-programming, video-streaming, rtp, rtcp

I want to be able to intercept the packets of this stream and access the data from C++-code.
How do I do this in C++-code?
The RTP- media stream are streamed using this server: [link](https://metacpan.org/source/REVMISCHA/RTSP-Server-0.06)

I will then FEC-encode the packets; send them over the network; FEC-decode them on the receiver-side and pass the stream of data to a RTCP-client.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate some opensource stacks for media streams like ( live555, openRTSP, VLC, mPlayer ). with any of these you can do the following:

```
 - install    
instrument    
build    
run with sample streams    
observe debug and   or logger
```

For example, in live555 source...

./live/liveMedia/MultiFramedRTPSource.cpp:MultiFramedRTPSource::~MultiFramedRTPSource()

you would have the frame handlers found [here](http://snipplr.com/view/57979/rtp-packet-handler/)

for another example , see [here](http://pastebin.com/2uDn1HSi) for log of a player ( VLC ) getting the stream ( rtsp / rtp ) available from any Youtube entry. If you want, you can drill any youtube videoID for a related streaming link. Then you could use that link for a source in your testing.